# Line and colon separated list to array PHP

Tags: php, associative-array

I'm trying to work out a simple way to take a list, like this

```
foo: Alpha
bar: Bravo
fooBar: Charlie
```

And turn this into an associative array so that values would be

```
$array['foo'] //would contain Alpha
$array['bar'] //would contain Bravo
```

etc.

What is the cleanest way to achieve this ?

Comment: [parse_ini_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-string.php)

Comment: Do you have a string like `foo: Alpha\nbar: Bravo\nfooBar: Charlie` or an array like `["foo: Alpha", "bar: Bravo"...]` or is the list a DOM element like table or ul or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
$string = "foo: Alpha
bar: Bravo
fooBar: Charlie";

$array = array();
$lines = explode("\n", $string);

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    list($key, $value) = explode(": ", $line);
    $array[$key] = $value;
}

var_dump($array);
```

Result:

```
array(3) {
  ["foo"]=>
  string(6) "Alpha
"
  ["bar"]=>
  string(6) "Bravo
"
  ["fooBar"]=>
  string(7) "Charlie"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick, but had to check the value first, so I didn't get an array returned as a blank last value.

if (strpos($line, ': ') !== false)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it manually if your first list is already in an array:

```
$array = [];
$list = ['foo: Alpha', 'bar: Bravo'];

foreach ($list as $element) {
    $parts = explode(': ', $element);
    $array[$parts[0]] = $parts[1];
}
```

Otherwise, simply use [`parse_ini_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-string.php) to parse a string that contains your data into an associative array (note that this function requires PHP 5.3 or greater).

If your data is in a string, and you don't have PHP 5.3, you can split on new lines to get an array: `$list = explode("\n", $string);`.

Comment: You're correct, that's a typo. Too much coding in Python these days ;).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is overkill but if your file format is likely to expand, it's worth looking into YAML, your example happens to be valid YAML markup. So you could for example use the [Symfony YAML component](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/yaml/introduction.html)

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;
$array = Yaml::parse('/path/to/file.yml');
```

It works with your current format and if you decide to add nested arrays or other non-trivial data, just use the YAML syntax, which is quite intuitive. Here is an introduction to the format:
http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/yaml/yaml_format.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this : 
    $array  = array();

```
$str    = 'foo: Alpha';
$res    = explode(":",$str);
$array[$res[0]] = $res[0];
```