# Extract number values from string in WordPress custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields, codex

Inside WordPress, every post has a single custom field with this kind of "value":

```
HTML:5, JQUERY: 20, PHP:38
```

This value is different in every post, not only for numbers, but also for names. I mean that other post could have:

```
CSS:90, HTML5: 32, LINUX: 80, ETHERNET: 22
```

Considered this, I want to extract and print every name (for example `HTML`) and the number of that name (for example `5`).

Sometimes it could happen that a number is part of the name (ex: `HTML5`), so I think that the only way would be to recognize string before and after ":", considering that the last one won't have "," at the end.

I'm conscious it would be much easier to have more custom fields, one per "name" like `HTML:5` and other one called `JQUERY` with value `20`, but it would be really long.

Comment: want a pure PHP solution ? did you tried something ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Line and colon separated list to array PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086520/line-and-colon-separated-list-to-array-php)

Comment: I've tried sht like preg_match('/HTML:\s*(\d+)/', $str, $html_value);
Nothing else. For sure I need pure PHP, not plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will probably work just as well as anything else.

```
    $string= 'CSS:90, HTML5: 32, LINUX: 80, ETHERNET: 22';

    $ar=explode(",",$string);

    foreach($ar as $item){
       $v= explode(":",$item);
       $array[]= array( 'key'=> $v[0], 'text'=> $v[1]  ); // or print html etc....

    }

    var_dump($array);
```